# How do you deploy a continuous running app when using npm-cli

Tags: node.js, git, pm2, npm-ci

I have a largish nodejs based web app, with both server and client components working together.  I am currently deploying the app, but using `git pull` to take my latest production branch from the server repository.  A git `post-commit` hook runs to do a `npm install` and a rebuild of the servers `.env` file, and PM2 is monitoring the various processes (3 web servers) using a change in the .env file to restart them.

node_modules is at the highest level of the project with separate server and client subdirectories.  Since this is using http2 on a fast lan, I don't bother compressing the client files with web-pack or the like, although I do use rollup on `lit-element` and `lit-html` to sort out the import statements (they are not relative or absolute) that they have embedded in them.

I've just been reading that I should really have been doing an `npm ci` for my node dependencies, but reading the instructions for that it says it blows away the node_modules directory and starts again (whereas `npm install` doesn't).  Since this is all running on a raspberry pi its not instantaneous.

I am not sure a temporary loss of node_modules should effect a running app too much - after all I believe the modules will all have been cached into memory, but it just might have not and there also a possibility that one of the servers falls over and pm2 restarts it, so I am wondering ....

So what is best practice here.  Is it possible for instance to copy `package.json`, `package-lock.json` to a special `build` subdirectory, build the `node_modules` directory there and then move it back into place. Once built. Or is there a better way?